# How to get the DateTime format in Utc?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table which stores DateTime column as Utc values "2019-03-12 09:42:14.39 +00:00". When i try to fetch the value and convert it into DateTime using **Convert()** function it converts it back to my local time(my system time). I used

```
DateTime.TryParse(dateTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture , DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dt)
```

This works fine and preserves the utc format but the issue is it converts the date from "12-03-2019 09:42:14" to "03-12-2019 09:42:14". Is there any better way to do this or how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: That code isn't T-SQL. Are you actually doing this in SQL Server? What value are you expecting when coverting `2019-03-12 09:42:14.39 +00:00` to a `datetime`? I *would* expect `2019-03-12 09:42:14.390`, as the `datetime` datatype has no space to store the timezone of a time; thus that information is "lost".

Comment: This is in SqlServer 2012. I am expecting 12-03-2019 09:42:14 as my output.

Comment: Then where are you running that? As I said, that **is not** T-SQL.

Comment: Changing the tags. Forgot to add in the first place.

Comment: You might want to have a look at TryParseExact method
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: If you are using a DateTime object do not change the UTC DateTime.  Local Time is only important when input or output the time as a string.  So when display the Time use the ToString() method.   Otherwise do not change the object.

Comment: If `12-03-2019 09:42:14` is converting to `03-12-2019 09:42:14`, sounds like someone is using a `string`/`varchar` to store date & time values, and when the ``string`/`varchar` is being read by C# is it being implicitly read in the format with the month and days switch to what they are (unsure is `12-03` is 12 March or 03 December). If you are using a `string`/`varchar`, there's your first problem.

Comment: The data is being stored as DateTimeOffset. I wrote an sp which will fetch values, now i take every row one by one , take the dateTime value as a string from inside that and i am having problem when i try to convert it back to the original format i.e the Utc time. That is my issue.